# Java SuperClass over writing subclass variables

Tags: java, inheritance, global-variables

I have a project that involves creating objects of varying types that inherit methods and variables from a super class, but when I try to change the variable in the subclass (to a value inputted through the constructor) the variable remains the same value it is initialized to in the super class.

This is one of the variables the super makes:

```
public int grade = 0;
```

and this is what happens in the subclass (newGrade comes through the constructor).

```
System.out.println(newGrade);
newGrade = grade;
System.out.println(grade);
```

Output shows newGrade = 1 (or whatever is selected) but grade = 0

I'm not sure if its something simple or something i've overlooked but I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: you are setting grade's `value` to the `newGrade`, you need to flid that statement:
`grade = newGrade;`

Comment: grade should == 0 from what I see here...  If you want grade to change you need to switch to   grade = newGrade;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You assign from right to left. So what you do here is print out `newGrade` (which is 1)
then assign it `grade` which is 0 then you print out `grade` which is still 0.

There are several problems here:

```
public int grade = 0;
```

This is trouble. The java guidelines state that you should use `private` variables (or no instance variables at all if possible). This way you can't make sure that some other (probably careless) programmer on your team does not tamper with `grade`.

```
newGrade = grade;
```

Since only copies of references are passed to methods/consturctors it is problematic if you try to reassign their values. It won't be reflected to the original object.

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you! I hadn't noticed i'd got them the wrong way around!

Comment: I'd say it's a higher risk that a careless programmer will tamper with the field than a malicious programmer. But by being careless, one could argue that this is in itself being malicious.

Comment: Sorry bad wording. It was supposed to be irony.

Comment: Done! Private variables seem to make compiling errors in this, fortunately its a solo mini project but i'm not entirely sure why this is.

Comment: They are making errors because you use those `public` fields elsewhere.